# vscode terminal doesn't recognize externals

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, terminal

I can't run external commands in the terminal like I can in cmd.exe

I am using vscode 1.50.1
I have environment variable PATH set to:

C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python\Python36;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin;C:\Users\axw04\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Users\axw04\AppData\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\axw04.platformio\penv\Scripts;

In the normal cmd.exe I can run the dotnet command without any problem:
eq. dotnet --info

But in the terminal of vscode I get an error

'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I also tried switching to powershell as default shell without any luck.
I reinstalled the latest

.NET Core 3.1 SDK (v3.1.403) - Windows x64 Installer

nothing seems to work.

my system is a windows10 laptop.
I have both vscode and visual studio 2019 installed.

Comment: Is that the PATH value actually verified from within Code or the one you expect it to be?

Comment: Run `set PATH` from the integrated terminal to see which environment was inherited.

Comment: running command  "set path" in vscode terminal yields this:
Path=C:\Users\axw04\.platformio\penv\Scripts;C:\Users\axw04\.platformio\penv;C:\Users\axw04\.platformio\python3;

it seems to be different from the environment variable PATH.
how do I sync the two?

Comment: You can configure VSCode's `terminal.integrated.env.windows` setting.

Comment: I have tried setting the options "terminal.integrated.env.windows" but it doesn't seem to have any effect. 
only thing that works is when I manually do

set Path="c://program files//dotnet"

in the integrated terminal

Comment: In your settings, do you have any non-default value at Features/ Terminal?